# How to read TLV data from InputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, io, network-programming, inputstream

Java program will be receiving something like "0x040x060x112233445566", consider the specified TLV indicates:

- **0x04 is Tag** indicates type of value(e.g. temperature sensor , speed etc)
- **0x06 is the Length** of value in bytes(6 bytes in this case)
- **0x112233445566 is the Value** (such as temperature , speed, battery etc)

such data will keep on coming to my socket's inputstream(every x milliseconds) ,how to read such TLV Data ? I tried to read it as a String using BufferedReader's readLine() , but then processing that data (separating(requires a delimiter) each hex value and converting it into decimal values(for validating purpose))is a bit messy, is there a better way to read this kind TLV data from inputstream.

Note:

- The 0X prefix will not be present in the actual data, I just used it here to differentiate between hex fields
- The actual data will contain multiple TLV elements.

Comment: Use a `DataInputStream`: `readUnsignedByte()` twice, and then `readFully()` for the length specified in the second byte.

Comment: I need to do this procedure for full data length(i.e. for all tlv(s)) , can I keep it inside a loop ? or shall I put the TAG inside a switch and then readFully() ?

Comment: in accordance to your suggestion: readFully() needs a byte[] and a java byte can only store within -127 to + 128, what about sensor values > 128 ?

Comment: 1. You'll need a loop to deal with the entire input stream. You'll need a switch to deal with the possible Tag values, but you can read each entire message before that. 2. Mask them with `0xff` when you read them. There is no unsigned byte in Java.

Comment: How about thread safety of DataInputStream, oracle documentation says , it is not safe for multi-threaded access, but this read-write mechanism is running on a separate thread at my end , & of course the UI Thread is apart from this , will this cause an issue when i'll be trying to print these sensor values onto an android activity ?

Comment: Well neither is your socket, is it? You will only be reading it from one thread. Otherwise all hell will break loose.

Comment: One more thing , the other end of the socket communication is supposedly writing a C a union(some protocol header (which contains a structure(as payload) ) , how to read this unsupportive types in java from socket?

Comment: If it isn't too late, get that changed. Don't use structs or unions as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols, defined in octets. What they are doing isn't guaranteed to work even between C programs let alone to another language. They should assemble the message into a byte array and send that.

Comment: am afraid they've already written the embedded c code for that, using unions & structs , basically they're type casting a handshake request(a union, it is a protocol header) to a user defined type "UCHAR8" unsigned 8 bit char* and payload :UCHAR8 payload[256] , this type according to them will accept values from 0 to 255 , how about now ?

Comment: Well you need to find out exactly what is put on the wire. The compiler may have inserted padding bytes. Get some sample messages and make sure about any padding between the type, length, and value fields. If there isn't any, just do what I said above. If there is you will have to consume it.

Comment: On comment No 4's Point 2 , you've asked to mask the byte with 0xff , but masking would work for max value up to 255 only right because its a byte[] after all, what about value greater than 255 ?